# Right side of admin panel disappears after updating my MODx Revo 2.2.15-pl to MODx Revo 2.3.0-pl

Tags: content-management-system, modx, modx-revolution

I've come across a strange kind of a bug or issue after updating my **MODx Revo 2.2.15-pl** to **MODx Revo 2.3.0-pl**

The right side of the admin panel just disappeared [after modx revo update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cFYVl.png)

However, if I install a fresh copy of MODX from scratch, this problem doesn't appear at all.

I have updated my site several times before without problems. I always followed the steps described in the official manual [Upgrading MODX Revolution 2.x](http://rtfm.modx.com/revolution/2.x/administering-your-site/upgrading-modx)

Maybe someone familiar with this situation can help me find out what's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find this is generally a symptom due to permissions on the /assets/ directory

- make sure the webserver has permission to read/write to /assets/components/ [and /manager/ and /connectors/]
- clear cache [always!]
- disable js/css compression
- make sure that the left panel is not actually collapsed [older versions was difficult to see the little arrow!]

Errors/problems should show up in core/cache/logs/ installation log.

Anyway, probably what has happened here is that you uploaded all your files VIA ftp as the ftp user & the webserver cannot overwrite those files. To make life easier on you, use the advanced install - that way all you have to upload are the /setup/ and /core/ directories [both should be read/write by the webserver as well]

Comment: Thank you for help! I followed your recomendations and everythig work just fine.

Goodluck to you! =)

Answer (score 1):

Also be careful with **.htaccess** in root MODx folder, try not change him, in some cases it causes issues. MODX Revo bug.